# Warning: ftp_get function

Tags: php, linux, ftp, ftp-client

I am calling this method `ftp_get($refConnection, $local_file, $remote_file, FTP_BINARY)`

facing this error

`Warning: ftp_get(/var/sandbox/client/api/clientapi/remote_files/OUTPUT/TRANSACTIONS/Transaction_2013_11_06_74130845_01.xml) [function.ftp-get]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/sandbox/client/api/clientapi/api_functions.php on line 159`

Answer (score 0):

That is a permission related problem, nothing to do with PHP code.

`chmod 777` the directory `/var/sandbox/client/api/clientapi/remote_files/OUTPUT/TRANSACTIONS/` and retry your code.